# My request won't repeat itself after executing

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

So I have a request in Postman that will create a User for me. I want to run it automatically for a certain amount of time to save time preparing datas. I try using setNextRequest but it doesn't work. I have tried to put it in Pre-request Script, Tests tab of the request itself as well as the Collection but it just won't run. I have certainly sure that all of my item is saved, none of them has orange dots.

```
var count = 0;
while(count < 5){
    postman.setNextRequest("CreatePersonWithUser");
    console.log("This is the " + count + " time");
    count++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the output in your console?

Comment: It's print the "console.log" five times then run my request last. Therefor, setNextRequest is not working and I don't know why.